# transformar datos de una consulta oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

alguien que me ayude. me piden hacer una especie de transformación de la salida de una consulta sql es decir tengo el siguiente query y da como salida.

```
SELECT nombre, apellido1, semestre FROM personas ``

nombre     apellido1     semestre
ANTONIO      PEREZ         2
ANTONIO      GARCIA        7
LUIS         LOPEZ         3
```

lo que quieren es que esa consulta no muestre los datos sensibles que hay en la tabla, los datos sensibles como los nombres de clientes, quieren que se sustituya al momento de traer el resultado de la consulta y mostrando únicamente los datos que se validen como no sensibles

```
nombre       apellido1   semestre
fulanito1    may1           2
fulanito2    may2           7
fulanito3    may3           3
```

Comment: la salida esperada debe darse ejecutando el mismo sql?

Comment: no necesariamente, espero me puedas dar una idea como hacer esa solución

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que se desea es tener un resultado aleatorio es bastante complicado indicar una sola forma de poder real izarlo, sin embargo podrías obtener algo similar a lo que muestras con el siguiente sql.

```sql
SELECT 'fulanito'||ROWNUM
,      'may'||ROWNUM
,      semestre
FROM   personas;
```

Comment: Hola lo que realmente quiero hacer es que de las tablas que ya existen, quieren encriptar algunas columnas por ejemplo las que tengan información de tarjetas de usuarios